# Plot a matrix in graph with two axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I need to plot a NxN matrix 'M' full of zeros, but only show the cases where m(x,y) is different from 0.

```
t_max = 10; % set the maximum number of iterations
n = 10; % dimension n*n
d = 1; % the probability of changing place
x = randi([1 n]); % random row
y = randi([1 n]); % random column
grid = zeros(10); % set an empty gride n*n
grid(x,y) = 1; % put an agent in a random place
for t=1:t_max
    newgrid = randomwalk1(grid,d); % call the function random walk for one agent
end
```

I tried `image(m)` but it's not giving satisfying results since I need also to keep track of the element that is different to 0, `hold on` doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `spy()` function. Just type `spy(m)` and see what happens.

Comment: that's working correctly, let suppose now that I have different numbers and I want to plot each set of numbers in a specified color.

Comment: @MP.Chal Than you are really looking for an image. Try to look at `imagesc()`.